# Java ForkJoin Future seems to finish prematurely

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I'm totally new to the jsr166y library and I've written a routine using the forkjoin library that splits up a query and runs it against database replicas concurrently. I've put a snippet below. The SelectTask extends RecursiveTask.

```
ForkJoinExecutor fjPool;
    Future queryResultsFut = null;
      for (int i = 1; i <= lastBatchNum; i++) {
```

...

```
  SelectTask selectMatchesRecursiveTask = new SelectMatchesTask(loadBalancer.getDao(), thisRuleBatch, queryResults);
  queryResultsFut = fjPool.submit(selectMatchesRecursiveTask);
}

queryResultsFut.get();
```

The call to the get method is intended to block the parent thread until all query results are returned so that processing can commence on the aggregated results.

I've discovered now after some time running in a CI environment that this does not always happen. When there is a slow database then then thread will continue even if tasks are still running. This seems to me to contradict the documentation I read.

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way? Should I extend ForkJoinTask instead of RecursiveTask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be using ForkJoin for this at all. The FJ framework is specifically designed for CPU intensive *non-blocking* task parallelism, but you are specifically using it for blocking tasks (external db queries). I would suggest you use the normal executor framework for what you are trying to do.

The only aspect of FJ that matches your problem is the task decomposition. This though isn't going to be too difficult to roll by hand, either by a simple n-way division or by a more sophisticated recursive strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment. Would you happen to know if the executor framework includes something that will look after the "wait for all done" aspect that I had assumed fork join was designed for?

Comment: Actually it looks like I should use the Phaser to implement a CyclicBarrier with the ForkJoinPool :  http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/jsr166ydocs/jsr166y/Phaser.html

Comment: Not sure why you want to wait for them all to complete but `ExecutorService.invokeAll(Collection<Callable<T>>)` returns a `List<Future<T>>` of results. As you iterate over that and get the result of each future that blocks until the future is complete, so you don't complete the iteration until all work is done. If you want to get the results in completion order you can use a `CompletionService`.

Comment: Basically I aggregate all the query results together and need to process them as one set. I sped up this query by running on multiple database nodes concurrently. Thanks for the information!

Comment: I ended up running into a problem which was something to do with the work stealing aspect of fork join. So I did end up changing it to a taskexecutor completion strategy. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

RecursiveTask inherits it's get functionality from ForkJoinTask so extending ForkJoinTask wouldnt have a different effect.  Keep in mind each time you submit you will get a different ForkJoinTask returned.  How many times are you invoking fjPool.submit?  If you are doing it more then once you will get the last task you submitted and thus queryResultsFut will complete (ie return from the get) when the last task completes.

Since you are dealing now with a ForkJoin pool you should expect back a ForkJoinTask after submitting instead of a Future.  The main purpose of the JF framework is for divide and conquer processing.  It is most useful when you are able to break up a problem into smaller similar problems, execute them in parallel then combining the results and returning.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I had assumed that the framework had something in place via the future to share the future instance and use it to wait for all fork tasks to be done.

Comment: Since you are using RecursiveTask the idea is to recursively submit to the fork join pool.  When you reach the end of the recursion set you would get the result and join it with a corresponding fork at the same level.  You return that result and repeat

Comment: But as far so what you are looking for consider an ExecutorCompletionService http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointers, I've tried using a phaser to wait for completion of subtasks and this seems to work (with minimal rewriting!) as I would like. you think there is anything wrong with this approach ?

Comment: I would think the best solution would be the completion service, but I dont see anything wrong with using a Phaser here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another fork-join method:
http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/ForkJoinArticle.html